# How to split HBase row key into 2 columns in Hive table

Tags: hive, hbase, external-tables

HBase Table 
rowkey: 2020-02-02^ghfgewr3434555, cf:1 timestamp=1604405829275, value=true
rowkey: 2020-02-02^ghfgewr3434555, cf:2 timestamp=1604405829275, value=true
rowkey: 2020-02-02^ghfgewr3434555, cf:3 timestamp=1604405829275, value=false
rowkey: 2020-02-02^ghfgewr3434555, cf:4 timestamp=1604405829275, value=false

Transfer HBase data into Hive table like below

Hive table
date =========   Id   ========   cf:no ==     boolean
2020-02-02 ====  ghfgewr3434555 ==   1  =======         true
2020-02-02 ====  ghfgewr3434555 ==   2  =======         true
2020-02-02 ====  ghfgewr3434555 ==   3  =======         false
2020-02-02 ====  ghfgewr3434555 ==   4  =======         false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem using 2 table/View. First 1 just coping data from HBase table and second table/view split the rowkey into 2 columns.

First Table query in Hive

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase_hive_table(
  key string,
  t1 boolean,
  t2 boolean
) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH 
  SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = "cf:1#b,cf:2#b) 
  TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "hbase_table");
```

First Table/View query in Hive

```sql
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS hbase_hive_view 
AS SELECT 
  CONCTNS.rowkey[0] AS date, 
  CONCTNS.rowkey[1] AS req_id, 
  t1, 
  t2 
FROM 
  (SELECT split(key,'\\^') AS rowkey, t1, t2 FROM hbase_hive_table) 
CONCTNS;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking to transfer it only to be queried, you can actually create a connection in hive to that table specifying the properties

```
CREATE TABLE foo(rowkey STRING, a STRING, b STRING)
STORED BY ‘org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler’
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (‘hbase.columns.mapping’ = ‘:key,f:c1,f:c2’)
TBLPROPERTIES (‘hbase.table.name’ = ‘bar’);
```

Proper doc here:
https://blog.cloudera.com/hbase-via-hive-part-1/

Comment: Yes, Query can be used. But I need to split the key into 2 rows.  "2020-02-02^ghfgewr343455" is a key and I need to split into 2 part, 1 is date and another is Id in hive table. How to split the key while transferring data from HBase to hive?